# sampling question

Tags: sampling, methodology, case-control-study

I have a question about inclusion criteria to obtain a representative sample of people with "sustained" or uncontrolled high BP. A colleague proposed that I look at health history data retrospectively (i.e. three years back), and include only members who have a BP of 140 over 90 consistently for all three years. I had asked what about those who only had a measurement of 140 over 90 in two or one years? And if they weren't consecutive? Although the rationale sounds logical, I would like a more research-based method.

Comment: It's not clear to me that this is a statistical question at all.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that this is a sampling question. This is a question regarding how your are defining the term "sustained, uncontrolled, high blood pressure" for the purpose of your study. The best way to define that depends upon the questions your are asking in your study.

The correct sampling question is how was the historic information that your are drawing from collected? Was it a random sample? If so, from what population? If the data is from ongoing records of an institution, you could randomly sample from that, but there are plenty of ways that could be a biased population to begin with.

That is as much as I can say without knowing more about your data. Perhaps someone with more background than me can contribute more. I hope that helps.